# RegEx to surround text that contains the string ";@tab;@tab;@tab;" with quotes

Tags: regex, pcre, regexp-replace

I'm trying to create a **PCRE RegEx** that **surrounds** strings that contain the string `;@tab;@tab;@tab;` with quotes (`"`). The input consist of multiple lines of text containing 1 or more columns separated with **tabs**. The strings that have to be surrounded with quotes (`"`) can be at the begging of the line, end of the line, or in the middle of the line. A line can contain **0 or more strings** that have to be surrounded.
Example:

```
1   some text with spaces
1   some text with spaces   anotherValue
1   some text with spaces   anotherValue    3452.2
val_so  some text with spaces   anotherValue    3452.2
val_so space    some text with spaces   anotherValue    3452.2
some text with spaces   anotherValue    3   other text with spaces

1   some;t@b;t@b;t@b;text;t@b;t@b;t@b;with tabs
1   some;t@b;t@b;t@b;text;t@b;t@b;t@b;with tabs and spaces  anotherValue
1   some;t@b;t@b;t@b;text;t@b;t@b;t@b;with spaces   anotherValue    3452.2
val_so  some;t@b;t@b;t@b;text with spaces and;t@b;t@b;t@b; tabs anotherValue    3452.2
val_so space    some text with;t@b;t@b;t@b; spaces amd tabs anotherValue    3452.2
some text;t@b;t@b;t@b; with spaces  anotherValue    3   other text;t@b;t@b;t@b;with spaces;t@b;t@b;t@b;and tabs
;t@b;t@b;t@b; with spaces   anotherValue    3   other text;t@b;t@b;t@b;with spaces;t@b;t@b;t@b;and tabs
;t@b;t@b;t@b;;t@b;t@b;t@b; with spaces  anotherValue    3   other text;t@b;t@b;t@b;with spaces;t@b;t@b;t@b;and tabs
```

has to become

```
1   some text with spaces
1   some text with spaces   anotherValue
1   some text with spaces   anotherValue    3452.2
val_so  some text with spaces   anotherValue    3452.2
val_so space    some text with spaces   anotherValue    3452.2
some text with spaces   anotherValue    3   other text with spaces

1   "some;t@b;t@b;t@b;text;t@b;t@b;t@b;with tabs"
1   "some;t@b;t@b;t@b;text;t@b;t@b;t@b;with tabs and spaces"    anotherValue
1   "some;t@b;t@b;t@b;text;t@b;t@b;t@b;with spaces" anotherValue    3452.2
val_so  "some;t@b;t@b;t@b;text with spaces and;t@b;t@b;t@b; tabs"   anotherValue    3452.2
val_so space    "some text with;t@b;t@b;t@b; spaces amd tabs"   anotherValue    3452.2
"some text;t@b;t@b;t@b; with spaces"    anotherValue    3   "other text;t@b;t@b;t@b;with spaces;t@b;t@b;t@b;and tabs"
";t@b;t@b;t@b; with spaces" anotherValue    3   "other text;t@b;t@b;t@b;with spaces;t@b;t@b;t@b;and tabs"
";t@b;t@b;t@b;;t@b;t@b;t@b; with spaces"    anotherValue    3   "other text;t@b;t@b;t@b;with spaces;t@b;t@b;t@b;and tabs"
```

I tried the following **PCRE RegEx** *search RegEx*: `\b(([^\t]+);t@b;([^\t]+))\b` with `g` flag  *replace RegEx*: `"\2"` but it matches strings across multiple lines (the match doesn't stop at the end of the line) but I want every line to be matched separately.

Comment: We **can** see tabs when editing the question, please keep the tabs in the sample data.

Comment: You can omit the capturing groups, and omit matching a newline in the character class `[^\t\n]+;t@b;[^\t\n]+` https://regex101.com/r/SOh0CR/1 In the replacement use the full match between double quotes.

Comment: Just use https://regex101.com/r/Mpo5mY/1, `[^\t\n]*t@b;t@b;t@b[^\t\n]*` and replace with `"$0"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the data is separated by tabs, and you don't want to cross newlines, you can exclude them from matching by adding a newline in the negated character class.

You can omit the word boundaries, as it will for example not match the `;` at the beginning and end in `;t@b;t@b;t@b;`

You don't need the capturing groups, because you want to replace the whole match between double quotes.

```
[^\t\r\n]+;t@b;[^\t\r\n]+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FKdru4/1)

In the replacement use the whole match between double quotes.

```
"$0"
```